# auto format text input into 24 hour format?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

In access, you can actually set a textbox to auto format to a time:

if you type 1:20p, it'll reformat it to 13:20
if you type 1.20p, it'll reformat it to 13:20

I would actually like to take it a bit further. I would like the above and the following examples to work

120p reformats to 13:20
1320 reformats to 13:20

Does anyone know of a class function or maybe even a 3rd party library that provides this type of functionality, or god help me, how would I do it myself? It seems pretty involved. I would have figured this would already be available.

Comment: Would the input be as `1:20p` or `1:20 PM` ?

Comment: preferably just p in the interest of speed entry